# Mathematica ListPlot two columns from the same table as (x,y) plot

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm new to Mathematica, trying to `ListPlot` set of data having time in the first column and values in the columns 2 and 3.

```
t = Import["/.../time_deltas.csv", "CSV"]

{{11.1694,0.,0},       {11.1697,0.000275,0}, {11.1702,0.000495,0}, 
 {11.1702,0.000028,0}, {11.1702,1.*10^-6,0}, {11.1702,0.000033,0},
 {11.1707,0.000502,0}, {11.171,0.000314,0},  {11.171,4.*10^-6,0}, 
 {11.1711,0.000025,0}, {25.8519,0.000029,1}, {25.852,0.000049,1},
 {25.852,0.000032,1},  {25.8521,0.000031,1}, {25.8524,0.000388,1},
 {25.8524,1.*10^-6,1}, {25.8525,0.000051,1}, {25.8543,0.001852,1},
 {25.9342,0.079813,0},{25.9391,0.004914,0}}
```

Plotting a single point I expected that:

```
ListPlot[{t[[1,2,1]],t[[1,2,2]]}]
```

Would plot a single point with `x=11.169662` and `y=0.000275`. Instead it plots two points with `x=1,2` and `y=11.169662, 0.000275`.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I don't see two points with what you showed. But I also get errors when having three subscripts. This seems to work for me ListPlot[{t[[2,1]],t[[2,2]]}].

Comment: @perror Thanks. And sorry i didn't respond earlier - didn't realize need to refresh the page. It should be 2 subscripts. *Dimensions[t]* produces {66342, 3}

Answer (score 0):

You need to group the data into x-y pairs for each list plot, e.g.

```
u = {{#1, #2}, {#1, #3}} & @@@ t;
v = Transpose[u];
GraphicsColumn[{ListPlot[v[[1]]], ListPlot[v[[2]]]}]
```

`v[[1]]` shows the data pairs you expect:

> {{11.1694, 0.}, {11.1697, 0.000275}, {11.1702, 0.000495}, ... }

Comment: Thanks a lot. Copied your code - produces exactly what i was looking for. Will have to figure out why *ListPlot[{t[[All,1]],t[[All,2]]}]* does not produce the same plot. Thanks again

Comment: That would be `ListPlot[Transpose[{t[[All, 1]], t[[All, 2]]}]]` or shorter: `ListPlot[t[[All, {1, 2}]]]`

Comment: Works great. Thanks. What are the advantages of the way you suggested first is the simple one works? Performance?

Comment: Using `Apply` or `@@`/`@@@` is a great way to rearrange data into a function or formula because the parameters in each list can be referred to as `#1`, `#2` etc.  For rearranging into a simple list it's not so advantageous, especially if you just needed `t[[All,{1,2}]]`.  See [Applying Functions to Lists](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ApplyingFunctionsToLists.html)

Comment: Thanks Chris. Learning a lot from your replies.